# Angular JS ng-repat of JSON in a HTML table body

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the fallowing data structure:

```
var myDataStructure =


[
    {
        "Period": {
            "Name": "Period1",
        },
        "Data": {
            "Now": {
                "NowNames": [
                    {
                        "Value": "Name1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name3"
                    }
                ],
                "LaterNames": [
                    {
                        "Value": "Name4"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name5"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name6"
                    }
                ],
            }
        }  
    },     
    {
        "Period": {
            "Name": "Period2",
        },
        "Data": {
            "Now": {
                "NowNames": [
                    {
                        "Value": "Name7"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name8"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name9"
                    }
                ],
                "LaterNames": [
                    {
                        "Value": "Name10"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name11"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "Name11"
                    }
                ],
            }
        }  
    }     
]
```

I want to print in a body of a table first rows with one cell holding the name value for  each NowNames for both periods and then print again rows with one cell holding the name value for each LaterNames for both periods. What is the best way to do that with AngularJ ? I am looking for the correct syntax, because first i have to do one  forEach to loop trough periods, and from the Period.Data values i have to print a row with values from the NowNames etc. something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Period in myDataStructure">
    <tr ng-repeat="Item in Period.Data.Now.NowNames">
        <td>
            {{Item.Value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="Item in Period.Data.Now.LaterNames">
        <td>
            {{Item.Value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

But no nested tr's because it is not valid and does not work
Expected result:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name7
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name8
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name9
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- after that the same for LaterNames in the same order.... -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes, i am looking for the right syntax for the one...

Comment: where's the expected html resultant layout? Please show what you tried

Comment: Sorry i would fix that wright away

Comment: do you just need this as readonly list? Easiest would be to map to new arrays

Comment: Pretty much, but i need it in a table, because the example i gave is simplified, because i just want the right syntax. The table will have some functionality though... I can make the data structure more simple like spreading it around in separate vars available to the scope and work around more than 1 nested repeat, but i was wondering if it can happen straight away, because i get the data structure from a service..

Comment: I would map the data in controller or service first, will be a lot easier

Comment: i did that, did a directive to load a template which will work with the data, made a controller, module and everything. in the controller i send request, from a factory I made, and get that data structure and i have to build a table from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with using nested ng-repeat:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="subdata in myDataStructure">
        <tr ng-repeat="nowName in subdata.Data.Now.NowNames">
            <td>{{nowName.Value}}</td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>

    <tbody ng-repeat="subdata in myDataStructure">
        <tr ng-repeat="LaterName in subdata.Data.Now.LaterNames">
            <td>{{LaterName.Value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZSB4/19/

Probably it is a better solution, to prepare the output already in the controller: Read the JSON and create a new JSON, which has the data in the right oder. This would make the output cleaner.

Comment: Yep... i think i will prepare the output, because it is too complicated to try to create something like that...